# Наследник формы не отображается в дизайнере

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть форма

```
public class frm : Form
{

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        this.Icon = Resources.remote;// иконка в ресурсах
    }
}
```

есть наследник:

```
public partial class frm2 : frm
{
    public frm2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Всё прекрасно билдится, иконка на месте. Но кода наследника пытаюсь открыть в дизайнере ошибка:

```
1.   Hide Call Stack 

at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

Что это такое? Возвращаю родителя снова в обычный Form - всё ок и в дизайнере.

На всякий случай скажу, что .Net 2.0

Comment: Скажите, а если родителя оставить `frm`, но иконку не менять - что получится?

Comment: @PavelMayorov то же самое. По факту, не могу унаследоваться от своей формы

Comment: Точнее, наследоваться могу (ведь всё билдится и работает как надо), но в дизайнер VS2015 с этим попасть не могу